# Checking the value of all a loops value

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have this loop in PHP that echoes out a table of results,

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Content Image Title</b></td>
    <td><b>Content Image Type</b></td>
    <td><b>Headline Image</b></td>
    <td><b>Content Image Belongs To</b></td>
    <td><b>Date Created</b></td>
    <!--<td><b>Uploaded By</b></td>-->

  </tr>
  <?php $colours = array("#f9f9f9", "#f3f3f3"); $count = 0;?>
  <?php foreach ($allContentImages as $contentImages) : ?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $colours[$count++ % count($colours)];?>">
      <td><?php echo "<a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='/media/uploads/$contentImages[categoryId]/$contentImages[contentImageName]'>".$contentImages['contentImageName']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $contentImages['contentImageType']; ?></td>
      <td><?php if($contentImages['isHeadlineImage'] == 1){ echo "Y";}else{echo "N";} ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $contentImages['contentTitle'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", $contentImages['contentImageDateUploaded']); ?></td>
      <td align="left"><a class="delete" href="<?php echo base_url();?>dashboard/deleteContentImage/<?php echo $contentImages['contentImageId'];?>"><img src="/media/images/icons/cancel.png" alt="Delete A Category"/></a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    if($contentImages['isHeadlineImage'] == '0') {
        echo "<tr bgcolor='red'>";
        echo "<td><p>You need to assign a headline image</p></td>";
        echo "</tr>";

  ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I need to check for each content piece with the same title that there is headline image, and if not then echo a new row that is red...but all I get is a new row every time there is an image that is not a headline image. Can anyone help me? I don't mind using javascript if that helps to match the values of the td's? But obviously my attempt is not correct.

Comment: Why are you jumping in and out of PHP code so much? It would be significantly more readable if you simply include the little bits of HTML into your PHP string, or precalculate the values rather than doing the calculations inline.

Comment: Or, my preference, the other way round: kick the `<a href='#'...` and `<tr bgcolor` strings out into the main content. Either way, you need to be calling `htmlspecialchars` over any text content you output to HTML, or you'll get XSS holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do has to be precalculated, since the `foreach` loop can not know about future content.

Maybe something like this before your `foreach` statement:

```
$contentHasHeadlineImage = array();
foreach ($allContentImages as $contentImages) {
  if ( $contentImages['isHeadlineImage'] == 1)
    $contentHasHeadlineImage[ $contentImages['contentTitle'] ] = true;
}
```

And then you can use

```
if (array_key_exists($contentImages['contentTitle'], $contentHasHeadlineImage)) {
  // Has headline image... 
}
```

to to verify if a certain title has a headline.

Answer (score 0):

Try my code below:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
  <tr>
    <td><b>Content Image Title</b></td>
    <td><b>Content Image Type</b></td>
    <td><b>Headline Image</b></td>
    <td><b>Content Image Belongs To</b></td>
    <td><b>Date Created</b></td>
    <td>Action</td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  $colours = array("#f9f9f9", "#f3f3f3");
  $num_colours = count($colours);
  $i = 0;
  ?>
  <?php foreach ($allContentImages as $row) : ?>
    <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $colours[($i++) % $num_colours]; ?>">
      <td><a href="#" class="screenshot"
             rel="/media/uploads/<?php echo $row['categoryId']; ?>/<?php echo $row['contentImageName']; ?>">
        <?php echo $row['contentImageName']; ?>
      </a></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['contentImageType']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['isHeadlineImage'] == 1 ? "Y" : "N"; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['contentTitle']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", $row['contentImageDateUploaded']); ?></td>
      <td align="left"><a class="delete"
                          href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard/deleteContentImage/<?php echo $row['contentImageId'];?>">
        <img src="/media/images/icons/cancel.png" alt="Delete A Category" />
      </a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php if ( $row['isHeadlineImage'] == 0 ): ?>
      <tr bgcolor="red">
        <td colspan="6"><p>You need to assign a headline image</p></td>
      </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

While tidying your code, I found an unclosed `a href` in the first column. For the special extra row, I add `colspan`. I assume `$row['isHeadlineImage']` have value only 1 or 0 (integer or boolean).

I also found out that you access array key without using quote. It can become potential bug in the future.

Write the code in tidy indentation and consistent when using block or echoing the php variable will help you found the bug quickly. Also, inspect the result in browser using Firebug in firefox or Web Inspector in Safari and Google Chrome to see if the page structure is like you want to have, all the tag is balanced and closed in right place.